# Installation of MSI File on remote machine from local machine

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer

Here is my script to install the msi file on remote machine:

```
Const MSIFileName = "\\<IP ADDR>\c$\MySetup\<FILENAME>"

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
WshShell.Run "msiexec /a " & MSIFileName & " /quiet /log c:\install.log", 1, True
```

When I run this script from the local machine, the file installs on the machine I am running from. Instead I want it to be installed on the machine specified in `MSIFileName`. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running a remote MSI on the local host. To install the remote executable on a remote host, you could use WMI:

```
host  = "<IP ADDR>"
setup = "msiexec /a ""C:\MySetup\<FILENAME>"" /quiet ..."

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://" & host & "/root/cimv2")

rc = wmi.Get("Win32_Process").Create(setup, , , pid)

If rc = 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Setup started with PID " & pid & "."
Else
  WScript.Echo "Starting setup failed. (" & rc & ")"
End If
```

The above will start the process asynchronously (i.e. `Create` returns immediately). If you need to wait for the remote process to complete, you'll have to monitor it like this:

```
Do
  WScript.Sleep 100
  Set p = wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID=" & pid)
Loop Until p.Count = 0
```

There may be simpler ways to do what you want, though, e.g. [`PsExec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553):

```
psexec \\<IP ADDR> msiexec /a "C:\MySetup\<FILENAME>" /quiet ...
```

Comment: I have another query on the same topic. If in case, I need to run the same as a different user, is that possible? (ie) specifying username & pwd in the script?

Comment: It requires a little more code, but it's possible. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290.aspx).